# Does "toggling" CSS in Javascript slow down the rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, rendering

I am investigating one possible reason why my website is very slow:

I have a Javascript function that gets called very often and determines for a lot of objects which of them should be visible and which should be invisible. It does this by adding/removing a CSS class 'hidden'.

This function works by first setting all elements to 'hidden', then following a bunch of rules to remove that class again from many of them. This happens immediately, with no delay, in the same function.

Quite often there will be no actual difference for any element after the function is done, but it still temporarily set the element's class to 'hidden' and then removed it again.

Does this "toggling" of a class cause the renderer to recalculate things that didn't actually change?

edit: To clarify: I am hoping that since Javascript is single-threaded, the renderer will only respond when the function is done, not in the middle of the function. If this is true, then the classes of the objects did not change from the perspective of the renderer, even though they were in fact updated temporarily.

Comment: "Does this "toggling" of a class cause the renderer to recalculate things that didn't actually change?". Of course it does if this statement is true "Quite often there will be no actual difference for any element after the function is done, but it still temporarily set the element's class to 'hidden' and then removed it again.". The reason is that "things did actually change".

Comment: I was hoping that since Javascript is single-threaded, the renderer will only respond when the function is done, not in the middle of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what the `hidden` class animates. Some properties are cheap to animate while others cost quite a bit as the browser needs to do more rendering.

Low-cost properties to animate are:

- position
- scale
- rotation
- opacity

The below image gives a good overview of which properties are easy on browser's resources and which cost more. The higher up the the charts to more resources are needed.

[image]
Source: [High Performance Animations](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)

To measure the performance of your function you can use [performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) to measure how long your function takes. Then, make some adjustments and see if it runs faster.

Comment: it sets "display:none"